# selenium webdriver Java_How Store Dynamic Text and Recall it later time in script

Tags: selenium-webdriver

im Stuck at one point and i need some guideline for that if any one suggest me how to perform these script then it would be really appreciated .
OK in my application i have to select employee country dropdownlist,employee state dropdownlist and employee code dropdownlist.
here im able to select any country then their states and employee code which is dynamics element(Either we can create new or we have select existing code and i NEED to store these element) each employee code contain 10 employee profile.
for example if my employee code is E001(it will contain UK employee profile only)
 hope u understand what i mean so in next page i have to click these employee code hyperlink(actually here i want my script should recall the stored dynamic element).
Following is sample script im using right now

```html
jxl.Sheet Sheet1 = wBook.getSheet(1);
String EmployeeCountry = Sheet1.getCell(2, 1).getContents();
new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("Fact-Communities-LIVE"))).selectByVisibleText(EmployeeCountry);
Thread.sleep(2000);
String EmployeeState = Sheet1.getCell(2, 2).getContents();
new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("Fact-Products-LIVE"))).selectByVisibleText(EmployeeState);
 
//selecting the dropdownlisted name by using INDEX 
new Select (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Fact-Camp_DropDown-LIVE"))).selectByIndex(1);


//Now how to store it and Retrive it Later ?
//after this i have to use these employee code here
//Following is Hardcoded script when we knew what employee code we have selected 
WebElement element7 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='opportunitiesDetails']//a[text()='EMP001']")));
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='opportunitiesDetails']//a[text()='EMP001']")).click();


//but how to do for dynamic element
```

Comment: What can be your "next page" URL?

Comment: Both page will have same URL .only difference is that above script is kind of uploading the employee profile under specific bucket (Page1) and next page(page 2) will be a list of all buckets contain lots of profiles and here i want to retrieve my bucket name to click & view profile name

Comment: you can use get text method to get bucket name.

Comment: i have used this script <String dropdown = driver.findElement(By.tagName("select")).getText();>

Comment: i getting bit confused its not working i m able to get text then using select action im not able to click these bucket that's getting  issue for me

Comment: Try to use wait until bucket appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, **you want to retrieve the text of the selected option in the dropdown, to use it later**. So, you can add the code below to retrieve the currently selected option.

```
//selecting the dropdownlisted name by using INDEX 
new Select (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Fact-Camp_DropDown-LIVE"))).selectByIndex(1);

//Retrieves the currently selected option from the dropdown.
String Option_Selected = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(#Fact-Camp_DropDown-LIVE"))).getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

Now, you can use it in the later code like this:

```
WebElement element7 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='opportunitiesDetails']//a[text()='"+Option_Selected+"']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='opportunitiesDetails']//a[text()='"+Option_Selected+"']")).click();
```

Furthermore, I would also suggest you to use **elementToBeVisible** method instead of **elementToBeClickable**; it is more reliable.

Comment: Hi Subh, I tried script given by you but got error while performing the Gettext Method();

Comment: Actually I had used "d" as the WebDriver instance in place of "driver". That must have been the error. Please check now, i have edited it..

Comment: Glad it worked it out for you.. Please accept this answer if it has helped you out.. Cheers.. :)